# Can one simplify this expression involving products of binomial coefficients?

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, factorial

I was wondering if there is a way to simplify the following expression. $N, M, L, K, n, Q$ are fixed natural numbers. Also n is supposed to be even.

\begin{align*}
\sum_{q=0}^Q & \sum_{l=0}^L (-1)^{Q-q+l} \binom{N}{q} \binom{M}{Q-q} \binom{L}{l} \binom{q}{l} \cdot \\ \cdot & \binom{Q-q}{L-l+K} \frac{l! (L-l+K)!}{(l+n/2-1)!(L-l+K+n/2-1)!}
\end{align*}

Hope someone can help me.

Comment: what are the three dots meaning ?

Comment: Just wanted to make it look better...

Comment: I mean, is it just a continuation of the  multiplication of the shown terms , is it? then please use just one dot

Comment: Thanks, edited it

Answer (score 1):

Since the expression is complicate, let's divide the summand into two blocks
$$
\eqalign{
  & A(q,l) = \left( { - 1} \right)^{Q - q + l} \left( \matrix{  N \cr   q \cr}  \right)
 \left( \matrix{  q \cr   l \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{  M \cr   Q - q \cr}  \right)
 \left( \matrix{  Q - q \cr  L + K - l \cr}  \right)  \cr 
  & B(l) = \left( \matrix{  L \cr   l \cr}  \right)
 {{l!\left( {L + K - l} \right)!} \over {\left( {l + n/2 - 1} \right)!\left( {L + K - l + n/2 - 1} \right)!}} \cr} 
$$
and treat them separately at first.

*a) Reduction of the A block*

Let's consider the four binomials depending on $q$
$$
 \eqalign{
  & A(q,l) = \left( { - 1} \right)^{Q - q + l} \left( \matrix{  N \cr   q \cr}  \right)
 \left( \matrix{  q \cr   l \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{  M \cr   Q - q \cr}  \right)
 \left( \matrix{  Q - q \cr   L + K - l \cr}  \right) =   \cr 
  &  = \left( { - 1} \right)^{Q - q + l} \left( \matrix{  N \cr   l \cr}  \right)
 \left( \matrix{  N - l \cr   q - l \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{  M \cr   L + K - l \cr}  \right)
 \left( \matrix{  M - L - K + l \cr   Q - q - L - K + l \cr}  \right) =   \cr 
  &  = \left( { - 1} \right)^{Q - q + l} \left( \matrix{  N - l \cr  q - l \cr}  \right)
 \left( \matrix{  M - L - K + l \cr   Q - L - K - \left( {q - l} \right) \cr}  \right)
 \left( \matrix{  N \cr   l \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{  M \cr   L + K - l \cr}  \right) \cr 
  &  = A_{\,1} (q,l) \, A_{\,2} (l) \cr} 
$$
where we have applied the *Trinomial Revision* to both blocks, and rearranged them:
now we have only two binomials depending on $q$.

*b) Separation of the sum in  $q$*

We can omit the upper bound on the two sums, since they are implicit in the  binomials
and write
$$
\eqalign{
  & S = \sum\limits_{q = 0}^Q {\sum\limits_{l = 0}^L {A_{\,1} (q,l)\,A_{\,2} (l)\,B(l)} }
  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,q} {\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,l} {A_{\,1} (q,l)\,A_{\,2} (l)\,B(l)} }  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,l} {\left( {\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,q} {A_{\,1} (q,l)\,} } \right)A_{\,2} (l)\,B(l)}  \cr} 
$$

The internal sum is
$$
\eqalign{
  & S_{\,1} (l) = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,q} {A_{\,1} (q,l)\,}  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,q} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{Q - q + l}
 \left( \matrix{  N - l \cr   q - l \cr}  \right)
 \left( \matrix{  M - L - K + l \cr  Q - L - K - \left( {q - l} \right) \cr}  \right)\,}  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,j\,\,\left( { \le \,Q - L - K} \right)} {
 \left( { - 1} \right)^{Q - j} \left( \matrix{  N - l \cr   j \cr}  \right)
 \left( \matrix{  M - L - K + l \cr   Q - L - K - j \cr}  \right)\,}  \cr} 
$$
and - for general values of the parameters -  the presence of $(-1)^j$ does not allow to put it in a closed form, if not in terms of a
[hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function), containing $l$ in its parameters, and computed at $z = -1$.
The advantage of a hypergeometric expression just depends on the use you are going to do of the whole expression.

*c) The terms  in  $l$*

The terms in $l$, besides $S_1(l)$, can be recasted in many different ways but - again in general -
there will be no any significant simplification.
Also here one possible expression would be through a [Generalized Hypergeometric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_hypergeometric_function)
with many parameters.